# Getting to key value pairs in joined data in spark with python

Tags: python

I have joined RDD withe following data set
this is the top 5 line in joined_datset , this is a joined data set
Key --PostModern_Cooking values (DEF , 1038)

```
ut[107]: 
[(u'PostModern_Cooking', (u'DEF', u'1038')),
(u'PostModern_Cooking', (u'DEF', u'415')),
(u'PostModern_Cooking', (u'DEF', u'100')),
(u'PostModern_Cooking', (u'DEF', u'597')),
(u'PostModern_Cooking', (u'DEF', u'786'))]
```

i am trying to create RDD  which returns like all the values DEF and the numbers

```
def extract_channel_views(show_views_channel): 
   key_value     = show_views_channel.split(",")  
   show          = key_value[1]
   channel       = key_value[2]  
    return (channel, views)
```

channel_views = joined_dataset.map(extract_channel_views)

when i run this i am getting error ,
my question is how do i get the key values in the function .if this is input file i am splitting (",") getting the key_value[1], key_value[2]is correct , but for joined data how do i separate each line get to individual key , value pairs .Thank you .

Comment: def extract_channel_views(show_views_channel): 
         key_value  = show_views_channel[1]
         show       = key_value[0] 
        channel    = key_value[1]   
        channel =int(channel)
     return (show, channel)

Answer (score 0):

You should try the nested tuple assignment like below:

```
key, (val1, val2) = ('testKey', (1, 'testVal'))
```

The value that you are receiving in the extract_channel_views functions is a nested tuple.

Comment: I figured out the issue , it passes the tuple just need to access with index , again index to access part of the key . I posted the code above .